# Cron job not executing script with docker exec

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, cron

I have created a bash script to run a backup of my containerized postgres database.  This script is called "do-pg-backup.sh":

```js
#! bin/bash
db=$(docker container ls -q --filter name=mydbcontainer* --format "{{.Names}}")
docker exec -it $db /etc/pg-backup/pg-backup.sh
echo "done pg backup"
```

If I execute the do-pg-backup.sh script in the ubuntu terminal ("bash do-pg-backup.sh") it runs perfectly as expected.

Now I have setup the following crontab so this script will run every minute ("sudo crontab -e"):

```
* * * * * bash /path/to/do-pg-backup.sh >> /tmp/cron.log
* * * * * echo "minute passed" >> /tmp/cron.log
```

My cron.log file looks like this after a few minutes:

```
minute passed
done pg backup
minute passed
done pg backup
...and so on...
```

However, the do-pg-backup.sh script is NOT successfully backing up the the db from the context of the cronjob.   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: perhaps add `2>&1` on the end of the crontab entry (to copy stderr to /tmp/cron.log) to see if there are any errors/issues with the script

Comment: @markp-fuso um how would I do that? (am very clumsy with linux)

Comment: edit the crontab (eg, `crontab -e`) to change the first line to: `* * * * * bash /path/to/do-pg-backup.sh >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1`; alternatively, how did you get those entries into your crontab to start with?

Comment: It now says "the input device is not a TTY" [scratching head]

Comment: I'd probably start with changing the shebang from `#! bin/bash` to `#!/bin/bash -x`; providing the full path to `bash` ==> `/bin/bash`, and the `-x` enables debug mode and should dump more info to stdout; removing the `-x` disables debug mode

Comment: also consider changing the crontab job from `* * * * * bash /path/to/do-pg-backup..sh ...` to include full path to `bash` ==> `* * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/do-pg-backup.sh ...`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the helpful hint from @markp-fuso, I discovered that I was getting the following error:

> the input device is not a TTY

After a little googling around, I made the following edit to do-pg-backup.sh script:

```
docker exec -i $db /etc/pg-backup/pg-backup.sh
```

Note: changed "-it" to "-i"

And it now works. I dont understand why it now works, but am happy it is fixed am my very important data is getting backed up.

[Source](https://serverfault.com/a/949718/311668)